# linux network traffic accounting

Tags: networking, iptables, traffic

I have a network with several Hosts N1, N2, N3, ... and they all communicate with each other.
I'm in the N2 host CLI with linux.
Can you know how much traffic was in bytes between a N2 Host and N3 in a period of time?
In this case, total traffic and not speed of communication.

Comment: You could possibly look into adding a custom IPTables rule that logs traffic from your host to a specific ip address. But I am not sure you would get aggregate traffic (packets I believe) in the logs, you might see that in the `iptables -vnL` output for the custom rule though.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
    iptables -N INET_IN  
    iptables -A INPUT -j INET_IN  
    iptables -A INET_IN -s 192.168.1.2
```

I send a file with NetCat of the Host 1.

```
    #100MB File
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=ffile.txt bs=1048576 count=100  
    cat ffile.txt |  nc 192.168.1.30 1001
```

In Host 2.

```
     nc -l -p 1001 > /tmp/x.x
```

View the result:

```
    Chain INET_IN (1 references)  
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination      
    2575  105M            all  --  *      *       192.168.1.2      0.0.0.0/0
```

And can use this command to flush results

```
    iptables -Z INET_IN
```